# Is it ok to hug in Abu Dhabi airport?

Tags: culture, abu-dhabi

I’m visiting my girlfriend who moved to Abu Dhabi for work.

Is it ok to hug when we meet at the airport or is it something we should avoid?

We are not married and it’s my first time in UAE, so I want to be cautious.

If it makes any difference, we are both Europeans.

Comment: You can probably get away with a hug, but why not wait until you are indoors. European makes a difference, but all it takes is one guard/officer/imam/whatever who is really unhappy.